# compute a division using list summary field in cognos report studio

Tags: division, cognos-10, report-studio

I have a Cognos Report created by a List. I used the Total function the report has to create a row of Totals, i.e. Total [TodayOrderCount] and Total [#ShipmentDaysOrder].

I then need to compute a division: Total [#ShipmentDaysOrder]/Total [TodayOrderCount]. For instance: 1,687/50=33.74

But instead the report shows 36.84 or any other number.

Does someone have experience with this?

Comment: Hi Liliana and welcome.  You have probably already checked, however I don't want to assume.  What is the detail and summary aggregation property for the data item? 
Try setting them both to calculated

Also, if that doesn't work, you could show an example of what the generated SQL is.  It might be a package/ framework manager model issue

Comment: Have you tried navigating to the query.  Then with the tool, create a query calculation 
Expression: Total [#ShipmentDaysOrder]/Total [TodayOrderCount]
Set the data item property for detail and summary aggregation to calculated